# Bulk products using rest Api with Rabbitmq custom queue

Tags: rest-api, magento2.3, rabbit-mq, message-queue, bulk-products-update

I want to create custom module in magento 2.3 beta to track the publisher message and processing message in consumer

Answer (score 0):

You can get an idea from here

https://webkul.com/blog/here-we-will-learn-how-to-configure-and-use-rabbitmq-in-magento-2-3/

https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/getting-started-with-message-queues-in-magento/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.That time I got a solution from devdoc.magento website.